# what is the proper syntax for getting an element out of a jquery array?

Tags: apex, jquery, array

I am new to javascript/jquery. I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to write the proper syntax for this. I would appreciate any help.

in apex you would do this :

```
Public list<project__C> projectDetails(){
    For(project__c p : projectDetails){
        if p == projectTabs__c.Id{
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something similar but with jquery. In plain english here is what i am trying to do

> "if focusedProject is the same a the projectTab's child p tag inside
>   of the array, then add class ui-state-active"

```
var focusedProject = '{!focusedProject}';
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName(".projectTabs");
var arrayOfAllProjectTabs = jQuery.makeArray(tabs);

for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfAllProjectTabs.length; i = i i + 1){
    if (focusedProject == ('ARRAYELEMENT.p_TAG goes here') )
    {
        $("DIV WITH == P TAG HERE").addClass('ui-state-active');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of why jQuery is just too complex for daily tasks. Too easy to use a hammer-type tool when you need a saw-type tool.

Comment: user7167 this site is dedicated to salesforce related questions, this looks very jquery specific, and is thus better asked at stackoverflow.com. Your first example could as easily been dummy code,java or c#. stackoverflow has many more jquery gurus and you'll get an answer much quicker there!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through the entire array if you already know the ID of the element you want to modify:

```
$("div:ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");  // Toggle "active" off all previous elements
$("div#"+focusedProject).addClass("ui-state-active");   // Find new project by ID and toggle "active" on
```

Make sure you're using CSS-safe characters, or you'll miss the element you're looking for.

Comment: hello, thanks for your response. Sorry i wasnt clear, the thing is i do not know which tab i want active - this will depend on what the user has clicked on in the previous page, which is why id rather loop through the tabs to match it with the salesforce id for the project

Comment: I am reading your response again, i think you may be doing what im asking for, but im not sure i fully understand it. do you mind giving me some more explanation ? Thank you

Comment: one more thing, sorry - you have three quotes("div#"+focusedProject+") should the second pair of quotes be only around the variable focusedProject? or also around both + signs? Thank you

Comment: Yes, the other quote was in error, I've updated that code.

Comment: jQuery lets you query specific elements and chain DOM functions onto them (most functions return a jQuery object).